# ViewHolder inflate takes too long when first inflating

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-viewholder

In my `MainActivity` with NavigationDrawer I switch between two fragments(by replacing them in FrameLayout):

- `FragmentA` containing `RecyclerView` with `ViewHolderA`
- `FragmentB` containing `RecyclerView` with `ViewHolderB`

In options I can choose which fragment is shown by default.

Layout of both ViewHolders is just a ConstraintLayout inside of CardView. Bind takes around ~5ms

When default fragment is `FragmentA`, `ViewHolderA` inflate takes ~40ms which causes application to lag. When I replace `FragmentA` to `FragmentB` from this fragment, inflation of `ViewHolderB` takes only ~7ms and recyclerview runs smoothly. When I once again replace `FragmentB` with `FragmentA`, `ViewHolderA` inflation takes only ~6ms.

However, when `FragmentB` is default, inflation of `ViewHolderB` takes 40ms. When I switch to `FragmentA` everything runs smoothly, like in previous case.

Why first inflation of recyclerview's viewholders takes soo long? Both recyclerviews have different adapters, but after this first inflation every viewholder in application inflates quickly.

My RecyclerView configuration:

```
layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
setItemViewCacheSize(20)
isDrawingCacheEnabled = true
drawingCacheQuality = View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH
```